# Can に関わりなく be used with adjectives?

Tags: grammar

にかかわりなく seems to come after a noun, e.g.:

> 文化祭は当日の天気にかかわりなく開催されます。
>   The school culture festival will be held regardless of the weather on the day.

Is it possible to use it with an adjective e.g.

> 文化祭は天気が暑いにかかわりなく開催されます。
>   The school culture festival will be held regardless of whether the weather is hot.

If not, how would I fix this sentence to make it grammatical?

Comment: A more helpful title might be something like "how to use にかかわりなく". Or "can にかかわりなく be used with more than nouns." So far all of your titles are very similar despite being about different grammar points. Since the purpose of this site is to make a collection of questions for everyone to use, it's something to consider.

Comment: so can u help me with this question ?

Comment: @Sam I am. Answering questions is just one way to help on this site.

Comment: I have trouble understanding your problem... Can you give us some example sentence which you think is correct? And do you know 関わる is a verb?

Comment: I have re-written your question in a way which I hope makes it clearer what you were asking. If I have misunderstood then please adjust accordingly. Leebo makes an excellent point, and I would add that if you want people to spend their time helping you then you should help yourself by spending more time writing a well thought out post with a relevant title, and a question that unambiguously explains your problem.